# C# - String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm getting the error "string not recognized as a valid DateTime". I've tried numerous formats but continue to get the error. I want to return "10/31/2019".

```
string x = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "2019-10-31T09:40:28-04:00", 
    "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss-K", 
    DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo).ToString("d");
```

Comment: I *think* the `T` needs to be inside single quotes.

Comment: The format string should be `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz`. `zzz` will match the time zone info.

Comment: Same error using: string x = DateTime.ParseExact("2019-10-31T09:40:28-04:00", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-K", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo).ToString("d");

Comment: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz"`

Comment: Thanks phuzi. It worked. string x = DateTime.ParseExact("2019-10-31T09:40:28-04:00", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo).ToString("d");

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the examples in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: @phuzi I didn't have a problem with `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format string should be `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK` or `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz`. notice the lack of `-` in the format string.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the -K is doing, you need a zzz there.

"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz" should be your formatter.

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```
string x = DateTime.ParseExact("2019-10-31T09:40:28-04:00", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo).ToString("d");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example the format for timezone is not `-K`. The minus character is part of the timezone (`K` format), not a separator between time and timezone. For example `-04:00` means "minus four hours". So it should be:

```
string x = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "2019-10-31T09:40:28-04:00", 
    "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK", // <-----
    DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo).ToString("d");
```

Answer (score 0):

The format string needs to modified as follows

```
string x = DateTime.ParseExact("2019-10-31T09:40:28-04:00", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo).ToString("d");
```